# create ftp accessible directory from php

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp, wget

How can I create a directory with php script, having some files in it, that can be accessed using ftp (with username and password) and not http (ex. by program such as wget)?

Actually I have multiple users uploading files to same server(using file-uploading form from a site) and server-side php script creates separate directories for each users' files. Now, I want those files to be able to be downloaded over ftp from a client machine running wget.

Please tell me how can I go about it?

Also, if any1 has a better way of doing it, please suggest..

Comment: `wget` can also download from `http:`

Comment: that is evn better, but can u tell me how can i restrict access to http downloads from a particular machine to certain directories only? I would like this restriction to be put using php

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html#allow

Answer (score 0):

PHP and FTP are 2 completely separate things. If you want the files to be able to be accessed, via ftp, you need to setup an FTP server on the machine hosting the files.

Comment: My host is providing ftp access to directories that are created using cPanel. How can I do the same work that cPanel does for creating ftp-accessible directory from php?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure-ftp server. They have a way of allowing users to login to the ftp from the database table data. You just need the php to create and write into the database the account.

The url is "http://www.pureftpd.org/project/pure-ftpd"